# Add extra data to Datalayer(GoogleTagManger) Magento2

Tags: magento2, google-tag-manager, magento2.3.6, magento2.3.x

I am working on GoogleTagManger module in my magento2.3.6.
i want to add price, brand and its values to the existing productClick event.

I tried the below steps in magento_catalog/product/list.phtml.. but didn;t work for me.
Please somebody give me some idea on this

```
<script>
                    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                    window.dataLayer.push({
                        "event": "productClick",
                        "ecommerce": {
                            "click": {
                                "actionField": {
                                    "list': "Catalog Page"
                                },
                                "products": [{
                                    "id":"<?= $_product->getSku() ?>",
                                    "price": "<?= $_product->getPrice() ?>",
                                    "brand": "<?= $_product->getAttributeText('product_brands') ?>"
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    });
                </script>
```

Comment: which error you are facing here?

Comment: Hi 
i dont see any error. just that my custom entries are not reflecting in ProductClick Event.

Comment: Have you check the above code, that is called when you click on that one?

Comment: Yes..  i have checked that. The function is being called. but the custom data is not sending to datalayer.